# Why doesn't the for loop give output?

Tags: c, loops

The problem is when I give an input it does not show any output. It just hangs.
I just can't figure out why the code is not working. Is it a limitation of C or does the code have something wrong with it? What actually is causing the problem?

for the input below:

```
2
http:\\lightoj.com
```

the program is meant to output:

```
https:\\lightoj.com
```

but it does nothing. I think the problem is with declaring multiple variables in for loop. Because if I don't use multiple variables in the loop inside else (instead of this `for(int j = 0, k = 0; j < l; j++, k++)` use this `for(int j = 0; j < l; j++)`) then the code shows output. (Of course not the expected one.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int T, n;
    scanf("%d", &T); // Test Case

    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) // Test case loop
    {
        char *s;
        scanf("%s", s); // taking a string

        if (s[4] == 's') // if the text has (https:\\lightoj.com) 's' in 4th index then it will //print the string as it is
        {
            printf("Case %d: %s\n", i+1, s);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Case %d: ", i + 1);

            int l = strlen(s);

            for (int j = 0, k = 0; j < l; j++, k++)
            {
                if (k == 4)
                {
                    printf("s"); // In the forth index printing s
                    j--; // changing j = 4 to j = 3
                }
                else
                {
                    // printf("i = %d j = %d\n", i, j);
                    printf("%c", s[j]); 
                    // printing each character of (http:\\lightoj.com) to (https:\\lightoj.com)
                }        
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

I did try multiple things to figure out where exactly the problem is. So I first check if the loop with multiple variable had any problem or not. Turns out it works. without the Test case loop. like this below

1)Checking individually

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{   
   //without the test case loop the program works fine. It gives proper output
    int i = 0; 
    char *s;
    scanf("%s", s);

    if (s[4] == 's') {
        printf("%s\n", s);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Case %d: ", i + 1);

        int l = strlen(s);
        for (int j = 0, k = 0; j < l; j++, k++)
        {
            if (k == 4)
            {
                printf("s");
                j--;
            }
            else
            {
                // printf("i = %d j = %d\n", i, j);
                printf("%c", s[j]);
            }        
        }
        printf("\n");
    }    
}
```

2. But if I Try this same code inside another loop (Test case loop) then it shows no output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int T, n;
    scanf("%d", &T);

    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++)
    {
        char *s;        
        scanf("%s", s);

        if (s[4] == 's')
        {
            printf("Case %d: %s\n", i+1, s);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Case %d: ", i + 1);

            int l = strlen(s);

            for (int j = 0, k = 0; j < l; j++, k++)
            {
                if (k == 4)
                {
                    printf("s");
                    j--;
                }
                else
                {
                    // printf("i = %d j = %d\n", i, j);
                    printf("%c", s[j]);
                }        
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

3. Inside test case loop if I change `for(int j = 0, k = 0; j < l; j++, k++)` to
   `for(int j = 0; j < l; j++)` it works but then I cannot use my logic to solve the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int T, n;
    scanf("%d", &T);

    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++)
    {
        char *s;        
        scanf("%s", s);

        if (s[4] == 's')
        {
            printf("Case %d: %s\n", i+1, s);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Case %d: ", i + 1);

            int l = strlen(s);

            for (int j = 0; j < l; j++)
            {
                if (j == 4)
                {
                    printf("s");
                    // j--;
                }
                else 
                {
                    // printf("i = %d j = %d\n", i, j);
                    printf("%c", s[j]);
                }        
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/ I.e. go back to something which does give output. If necessary a HelloWorld. Then increase complexity, first by adding a basic everyday count-to-5 loop. Then built up towards your full program, making sure that the output stays.

Comment: @Galvatron This code snippet         char *s;
        scanf("%s", s); invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Please note that `char *s;` doesn't allocate any memory, it declares an uninitialized variable of type pointer to `char`.

Comment: Yes, I tried step by step, to figure out where the problem is. And it seems that the logic is correct but the syntax is not allowing that or something. The code when separately tested works fine. But doesn't work together.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow humm. This might be the problem, but it works fine if I do changes in the loops. Then it becomes unclear why char *s is working in some cases and not working in other cases.

Comment: @Bob__ But isn't it the way to declare strings in C?

Comment: @Galvatron Undefined Behaviour includes behaviour that seems to work (for a while, anyway). Until you fix that, you can't make any assumption that changing the loops is "fixing" anything.

Comment: @pmacfarlane That's also right. The thing is,  if I use char array[] I don't know the specific size of the array that I should use to take input from the user. as the user can give input from 10 to 1000 characters or even more. And even after that the array[] has to have at least one place for the null character, to use it as string.

Comment: @Galvatron Declare it with a fixed size that is "big enough", e.g. `char array[500];`then use `fgets()` to limit the input to that. `fgets(array, sizeof array, stdin);`

Comment: @Galvatron With `char *s;` , `s` is _not_ a _string_.  It is a _pointer_.  At this line, the pointer `s` has an indeterminant value.  `scanf("%s", s);` needs a pointer to a location to store the _string_.

Comment: save yourself from future headaches by using fgets/sscanf instead of simply scanf when dealing with keyboard input.

Answer (score 2):

At least these problems:

**Uninitialized pointer**

Code passes `s`, which lacks a specified value to `scanf()`.  As is, the result is *undefined behavior* (UB).

```
// Bad
char *s;
scanf("%s", s); // taking a string
```

Instead use a sizeable array, a *width* limit and check the return value.

```
char s[100 + 1];  // A location to store a string up to length 100.
if (scanf("%100s", s)  != 1) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Trouble reading.\n");
  return -1;
}
```

A better alternative would use `fgets()` - although that is problematic after the prior `scanf("%d", &T);`.  Best to use `fgets()` throughout.

```
char s[100 + 1];  // A location to store a string up to length 100.
if (fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin) == NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Trouble reading.\n");
  return -1;
}
// Note that at this point, s likely contains a '\n`.
```

**Testing junk?**

`if (s[4] == 's')` should be be attempted unless the *string* in `s` is long enough.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your code has undefined behavior: you pass an uninitialized pointer to `scanf()` for the `%s` conversion specifier:

```
    char *s;
    scanf("%s", s); // taking a string
```

Undefined behavior means anything can happen.  Your program can stop with or without an error message, as you observe.

You should define `s` as an array, specify the maximum number of characters to store into the array and test for input failure:

```
    char s[100];
    if (scanf("%99s", s) != 1) {
        printf("missing input\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

Also note that the problem can be solved with a test and a `printf` statement.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int T;

    // read the number of test cases
    if (scanf("%d", &T) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "missing number of test cases\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
        char s[100];
        if (scanf("%99s", s) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "missing input\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if (strlen(s) <= 4 || s[4] == 's') {
            // no change needed
            printf("%s\n", s);
        } else {
            // insert an `s` before the fifth character
            printf("%.4ss%s\n", s, s + 4);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```